# accessing std::list inside struct induce segfault

Tags: c++, memory-management, struct, constructor, malloc

I currently cannot find the source of the segmentation fault from the following program.

```
struct info
{
    std::list<int> bfs;
    int *level;
    int *distance;
};

 ...

info* Graph::BFS(int s)
{
    info *tmp = (info*) malloc(sizeof(struct info));
    tmp->level = new int[V];
    tmp->distance = new int[V];

    ...

    tmp->bfs.push_back(s); !! <- causes a segmentation fault
    tmp->level[s] = 0; <- seems to work ok

    int current;
    std::list<int>::iterator i;
    while (!myqueue.empty())
    {
        current = myqueue.front();
        myqueue.pop();
        tmp->bfs.push_back(current); <- causes segmentation fault

     ....

    return tmp;
}
```

I've also tried to do the following, without success:

```
info *tmp = (info*) malloc(sizeof(struct info));
std::list<int> bsf;
tmp->bsf = bsf // and then call tmp->bsf.push_back()....
```

Comment: Don't use `malloc`.

Comment: why not ? should I just use new ?

Comment: That is incorrect as a way of creating `std::list<int> `.

Comment: `malloc` doesn't call constructors that are needed for non-trivial types, like `std::list`. Note that `info* tmp = new info;` is even simpler than the call to `malloc`.

Comment: Instead of these: `tmp->level = new int[V];` consider using a `std::vector` You'll get the almost same results with much less fuss.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in mixing C++ code with C code.

In this statement

```
info *tmp = (info*) malloc(sizeof(struct info));
```

a memory is allocated for the structure without calling constructors of its data members,

Instead of `malloc` you have to use the operator `new`. Otherwise the data member `std::list<int> bfs;` will not be constructed.